# `error warn Multiple Podfiles were found:` when creating a new react-native app

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, command-line-interface, zsh

I am creating a new react-native app using:

```bash
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

but I am getting this error:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✔ Installing Bundler
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
```

I tried creating the project with the --template option to specify the template to use.

```
npx react-native init MyProject --template react-native-template-ios-basic
```

but this is giving me different error.